# Interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I am interpolating a large gridded DSM in QGIS. I end up with 5 or 6  lines across the final raster, which drop (or raise) the elevation by c.5m if you plot a profile across them. Ther are relatively narrow in breadth.

I only see these if I set the grid size to 0.5m. If I set the grid size to c.1m, they disappear. I would like to interpolate to a smaller grid size if possible.

I've scoured through the data points, and it doesn't seem to be a data artefact from the sampling of the dsm, nor any downsampling I do afterwards in CloudCompare.

Has anyone else seen this, or know a work around?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.